# Google Sheets / Сменить формат ячейки если значения в ней совпадает с переменной

Tags: node.js, google-spreadsheet

Есть необходимость менять визуальное отображение значения переменной в ячейке (фон заливки, жирность начертания или цвет отображения), если оно совпадает с установлены образцом. `Conditional Formatting`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую разобраться с [документацией](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/conditional-format?hl=ru#node.js), но чёт пока туго. Вот что удалось напечатать.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const keys = require('./keys.json'); // доступы к API  
const client = new google.auth.JWT(
    keys.client_email,
    null,
    keys.private_key,
    ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
)

let testingName = "aaa"; // то по чем фильтруем, ищем совпадение

client.authorize(function (err, tokens){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }else{
        console.log('Connected');
        colorize(client) // ф-ция разукрашка 
    }
})

///// Теоретически эта функция должна сейчас поменять фоновый цвет для ячейки A1 Но оно не срабатывает не знаю что не так 
function colorize(cl){
    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", cl });
    const spreadsheetId = "19SXVyvV_58IDjwukm06OepvNOCWp5n2NJxBuNj9k4fU"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
    const ucfSelectedRowIndex = 1; // Please set more than 0.
    const request = {
        requests: [
        {
            "updateBorders": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": spreadsheetId,
                    startRowIndex: ucfSelectedRowIndex - 1,
                    endRowIndex: ucfSelectedRowIndex,
                    startColumnIndex: 1, // Column "A"
                    endColumnIndex: 2 // Column "A"
                },
                format: {
                    backgroundColor: {red: 1, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4},
                },
            }
        }
    ]
    };
    sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(
        { spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, requestBody: request, cl },
        function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            } else {
                console.info(response);
                console.log("Client Feedback Sent Col Values updated");
            }
        })
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста кто работает с данной API К сожалению приведенные примеры только [для php](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting) как написать для nodejs не получается разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Условное форматирование создается запросом [addConditionalFormatRule](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addconditionalformatrulerequest)

Примерно так выглядит отправка запроса:

```js
  res = await api.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId,
    requestBody: {
      requests: [
        {
          addConditionalFormatRule: {
            rule: {
              ranges: [
                {
                  sheetId: 0,
                  startColumnIndex: 2,
                  endColumnIndex: 3,
                }
              ],
              booleanRule: {
                condition: {
                  type: "TEXT_CONTAINS",
                  values: [{ userEnteredValue: "foo" }]
                },
                format: {
                  textFormat: {
                    bold: true,
                    foregroundColor: { blue: 1 }
                  },
                  backgroundColor: { red: 1, green: 1 }
                }
              }
            },
            index: 0
          }
        },
      ],
    },
  })
```

Значения для *spreadsheetId* и *sheetId* берем из адресной строки самой таблицы: *spreadsheetId* это хэш-строка, а *sheetId* это *gid* (для первого листа обычно равен 0).

В правиле указываем диапазоны ячеек (набор [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)) и одно из двух правил - либо [booleanRule](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#BooleanRule), либо [gradientRule](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#GradientRule) (нам будет достаточно первого).

*BooleanRule* разбито на две части: необходимое условие [condition](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#BooleanCondition) и применяемый при его выполнении формат ячейки [format](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellFormat). Возможные типы условий перечислены [здесь](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#conditiontype) (в примере использован `TEXT_CONTAINS`), а параметры форматирования [здесь](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellFormat).

Вот полный код демонстрационной программы (используется легковесный пакет [@googleapis/sheets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googleapis/sheets)).
При первом запуске в консоль выдается *url* страницы авторизации и ожидается ввод кода с последней страницы, после запроса токен сохраняется в файле `token.json` и последующие запуски используют его напрямую (если токен уже есть, можно скопировать его и не шаманить с командной строкой).

```js
const fs = require('fs/promises')
const readline = require('readline/promises') // node 17+
const { sheets, auth } = require('@googleapis/sheets')
const { installed } = require('./credentials.json')

async function runSample(spreadsheetId) {

  let client
  try {
    const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = installed
    client = new auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0])
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error loading client credentials file:', error)
    return
  }

  try {
    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    const token = await fs.readFile('token.json')
    client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token))
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 'ENOENT') {
      const token = await getNewToken(client)
      client.setCredentials(token)
    } else {
      console.error(error)
      return
    }
  }

  const api = sheets({ version: "v4", auth: client })

  res = await api.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId,
    requestBody: {
      requests: [
        {
          addConditionalFormatRule: {
            rule: {
              ranges: [
                {
                  sheetId: 0,
                  startColumnIndex: 2,
                  endColumnIndex: 3,
                }
              ],
              booleanRule: {
                condition: {
                  type: "TEXT_CONTAINS",
                  values: [{ userEnteredValue: "the" }]
                },
                format: {
                  textFormat: {
                    bold: true,
                    foregroundColor: { blue: 1 }
                  },
                  backgroundColor: { red: 1, green: 1 }
                }
              }
            },
            index: 0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  })

  console.log(res.data)
}

async function getNewToken(client) {
  const authUrl = client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
  })
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl)
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  })

  const code = await rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ')
  rl.close()
  try {
    const { tokens } = await client.getToken(code)

    // Store the token to disk for later program executions.
    await fs.writeFile('token.json', JSON.stringify(tokens))
    console.log("Token stored to `token.json`")
    return tokens
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('\nError while trying to retrieve access token\n', error)
    throw error
  }
}

const spreadsheetId = '_________________________________________'

runSample(spreadsheetId)
```

Добавлю, что создание правил условного форматирования через *api* мало отличается от их [создания](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413#zippy=) непосредственно в таблице: каждое новое правило добавляется к предыдущим, а не заменяет его, если условие выполняется сразу в нескольких правилах, то срабатывает только самое первое. Порядок правил определяет значение поля `index` и изменить его можно запросом [updateConditionalFormatRule](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updateconditionalformatrulerequest), ну и конечно же правило можно удалить запросом [deleteConditionalFormatRule](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deleteconditionalformatrulerequest). Правила не фиксируют формат при создании, а отслеживают изменение данных (и соответственно условия правила).

Если такое поведение вас в корне не устраивает, то можно пойти другим путем: первым запросом прочитать данные из таблицы, программно проанализировать их и сформировать данные для [updateCells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest) запроса.

Примерно так будет выглядеть запрос на выборочное форматирование ячеек:

```js
  res = await api.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId,
    requestBody: {
      requests: [
        {
          updateCells: {
            range: {
              sheetId: 0,
              startColumnIndex: 2,
              endColumnIndex: 3,
              startRowIndex: 10,
              endRowIndex: 14,
            },
            rows: [
              { values: { userEnteredFormat: { backgroundColor: { red: 1, green: 1 } } } },
              { values: null },
              { values: null },
              { values: { userEnteredFormat: { backgroundColor: { red: 1, green: 1 } } } },
            ],
            fields: "userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor",
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  })
```

Здесь в диапазоне из четырех строк формат применяется только к первой и последней строке, а в строках со значением *null* цвет фона будет сброшен в исходное состояние.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Возникли вопросы, буду благодарен если объясните 1) После того как в ячейке отформатировались стили, её стили не получается переназначить (фиксируются значения). => То есть, если совпадение  с текстом "the" произошло, то например поменять цвет фона скажем на красный уже, в этой ячейке, не получается.  Можно ли это как-то исправить ?

Comment: 2) Если в текущей, закрашенной ячейке сменить значение, "руками" на другое, то все форматировании ячейки тоже самоудаляются. Можно ли как-то это запретить...? Что б не менялись стили.

Comment: 3) Как можно модифицировать данный код если есть необходимость проверять каждую ячейку таблицы на массив значений? Например ["the", "foo", "abba"] ?

Comment: Дополнил ответ и добавил альтернативное решение. По последнему пункту не совсем понятно: _все_ или _одно из_. Если одно из, то можно создать три правила. В противном случае надо писать _условие-формулу_.

Comment: Спасибо, по последнему пункту - все из массива. Если хотя бы одно значение из ячейки совпадает с значениями в проверяемом массиве, что бы перекрашивало ячейку

Comment: Просто как показала практика, если есть необходимость проверить на совпадение в таблице >50 строковых значений, то сервер возвращает 'Request failed with status code 429' Подскажите, пожалуйста как эту проблему можно решить ?... практика показала что даже 50 раз вызвать одну и ту же функцию -это накладно для сервера

Comment: `batchUpdate` позволяет отправлять одновременно много запросов (поле `requests` - это массив).

Comment: И не забывайте, что  `ranges` может охватывать довольно большой диапазон и строк и колонок одновременно. Стоит сначала найти оптимальный вариант непосредственно в таблице, а потом уже работать через _api_.

Comment: То что ```requests:``` это массив я понимаю, но ведь в ключь ```values: [{userEnteredValue: 'проверяемая строка'}]``` можно за один запрос всунуть только одно значение на совпадение? Или нет?

Comment: `values` тоже массив, только тогда `ranges` должен охватывать соответствующее число столбцов.

Comment: Чёт всё равно недопонимание, вот сформировал такой запрос https://jsfiddle.net/dspxo7eq/ но возвращает  ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "booleanRule" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.``` Тут же вроде четко говориться что надо с1по14 колонку проверять с 3 по 12 ряд.... ну и запрос по Вашему первому примеру. Такое впечатление что эти правила не совместимые

Comment: Перед `addConditionalFormatRule` должна быть `{` - каждый элемент массива должен быть объектом.

Comment: Всё равно пока не дошло, https://jsfiddle.net/dspxo7eq/2/ Значение ключей ведь не могут повторяться... что-то не понимаю. Можешь, пожалуйста подправить данный запрос ?

Comment: Если `values` содержит массив, то надо так: `values: [{...}, {...}, {...}]` (просто для одного элемента можно квадратные скобки опускать)

Comment: phpStorm говорит что синтаксис неверен... ни так ```values: [{"aabb"}, {"aaa"}, {"baa"}]```  ни так  ```{values: ["aabb","aaa","baa"]}```

Comment: `values: [{ userEnteredFormat: {userEnteredValue: checkData[0]} }, { userEnteredFormat: {userEnteredValue: checkData[1]} }, ...]`